# Can we call our weekend a holiday?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm not sure if we can use holiday for our weekend or off days and holidays are considered the days in addition to our normal off days.

Saturdays and Sundays are weekends in my country but my friend doesn't work Wednesdays and Thursdays.

How can I ask about it?

- What days are your weekend?
- What days are your off days?
- What days are your ______?

If neither of the above sentences is correct what can I put in this gap?

Comment: In Malaysian English(MyE), we do use *holiday*. Alternatively, you can form a phrase from the word *break* such as school break, Christmas break or whatever. You can also use *gap* in some context.

Comment: I don't know about Malaysian English but I don't think we can use holiday

Comment: Yes, we do use it. Not only colloquially, I use it in my academic writing. However, it'll be hard to find a proficient English user will use that though.

Comment: thanks but what about the answer below? It makes sense and it helps more  if you open the link below. It says that holiday is referred to a longer vacation or public holidays like Christmas or Easter.

Comment: a word usages and meanings are different in particular places. Like *suspender* in US and British are different. Plus, I havent found any dictionary use MyE, they are mostly BrE and AmE. If you  are no Malaysian, dont use it to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, no, you cannot call typical weekends and typical days off "holidays".

> [holiday](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/holiday)
>   a day for celebration when many people are allowed to stay away from work or school:
>   *a national holiday*

For example,

> [Thanksgiving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_(United_States)), or Thanksgiving Day, is a public holiday celebrated on the fourth Thursday of November in the United States.

You can say *holiday weekend*, but this refers to weekends that coincide with an actual holiday, like Christmas Day Sunday, December 25, 2016. [Holiday weekend](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holiday%20weekend) also means a weekend that is preceded or followed by a holiday. An example is November 26-27, 2016. This holiday weekend follows Thanksgiving Day Thursday, November 24, 2016. This is often called a *long weekend*, since many people don't work on that Thursday and they take that following Friday off to have a *four-day* weekend.

In American English, when talking about days off, you wouldn't ask your friend "Are your holidays Wednesdays and Thursdays?", or "When are your holidays?", for example. Roughly, the first one asks "Are Wednesdays and Thursdays days for celebration?" and the second one asks "When are your days for celebration?" Instead, you could ask

- What/when are your days off?
- What/when are your off days?
- What days are you off?

*When are you off?* could work, but it has to be clear that you are talking about *days*. Otherwise, it could be interpreted as a question about the time that the person ends work. For example, *When are you off? I'm off at 3pm*. "What days are your off days?" works too.

You mentioned "what days are your weekend?" This question makes sense if it is understood from context that someone does not have a typical work or school week. So if you know your friend works on Saturday and Sunday (the assumed weekend), then you could ask "what days are your weekend?", "what's your weekend?", "when's your weekend?", "when does your weekend start?", etc. However, this usage is unusual, so I don't encourage it.

Answer (score 2):

I would ask "On which days do you get off?"

Weekend only refers to Saturday and Sunday irrespective of whether someone works on those days or not. Holidays usually is referred to a longer vacation usually around a public holiday like Christmas or Easter.

http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/holidayvsweekend.html